# Extract a hyperlink from a website - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was attempting to solve this issue for a bit of time and attempted multiple solution posted on here prior to opening this question.

I am currently attempting to a run a **scraper** with the following code

```
website = 'https://www.abitareco.it/nuove-costruzioni-milano.html'
path = Path().joinpath('util', 'chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "p1")))
```

My goal hyperlink has word `scheda` in it:

```
i = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@href, "scheda")]')
i.text
```

My first issue is that `find_element_by_xpath` only outputs a single hyperlink and second issue is that it is not extracting anything so far.

I'd appreciate any help and/or guidance.

Comment: If you want more than one element, call `find_elements_by_xpath`. Note the `s`. What do you mean by `extracting`? Extract what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find_elements` instead :

```
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@href, 'scheda')]"):
    print(name.text)
```

Note that `find_elements` will return a list of web elements, where as `find_element` return a `single web element`.

if you specifically looking for `href` `attribute` then you can try the below code  :

```
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@href, 'scheda')]"):
    print(name.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks I'm kind of new with Selenium and documentation is a bit complicating. One more thing, I've noticed that the output is unsorted; I can run matching script, but was wondering if there is a way to extract sorted `href`?

Comment: See, that's a python list. you can store them into an list in python and then there are multiple ways to sort 'em.

Comment: I mean sort based on its location on the web, currently MILANO2 is the first element, whereas in the list ADRIANO is the first, is that a normal behaviour?

Comment: I believe, by default it will be in lexicographical order, if you want to specifically sort based on custom order, there are few ways, but I'd ask you to create a separate ticket for that, since this  question is all about `Extract a hyperlink from a website - Selenium`

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 issues, looking at the website.

1. You want to find all elements, not just one, so you need to use find_elements, not find_element
2. The anchors actually don't have any text in them, so .text won't return anything.

Assuming what you want is to scrape the URLs of all these links, you can use .get_attribute('href') instead of .text, like so:

```
url_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/a[contains(@href, "scheda")]')
for i in url_list:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

It will detect all webelements that match you criteria and store them in a list. I just used print as an example, but obviously you may want to do more than just print the links.